# Unity Multiplayer: Reset player position when Y axis is less then -2

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, unique, multiplayer

i'm having this issue with resetting the players position when the players Y axis is less then the threshold value which is -2.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ResetPlayerPosition : NetworkManager {

    public float threshold = -2f;

    NetworkIdentity UniquePlayer;

    // On button click, it checks the players position and resets the position if values are true
    public void ResetPosition () {

        UniquePlayer = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
        var Player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");

        // Reset player position if the players Y axis is less than -2
        if (Player.transform.position.y < threshold) {
            Debug.Log("player position has been reset");
            Player.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Player position Y is currently at: " + Player.transform.position.y);
        }   
    }
}
```

My goal is to catch the unique players y position  and reset that to 1 if its less then -2. I got it working when you're in the match alone, but as soon as you're more than 1 player in the match, it does weird things because its not pointing to the specific player.

I'm using NetworkManager and its running on localhost. I've attempted my way around this with getting the netID of the player which is unique but can't figure out how to combine this information.

Hope someone is able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend doing some more testing to narrow down how the weird behavior differs on the host system and the client system. This might give some insight into what exactly is going wrong.

Second, I agree with Sebastian that putting a MonoBehaviour on the player prefab could be a better way to go. Something like this should be a surefire solution:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PositionReset : MonoBehaviour {
    public float threshold = -2;
    public float resetHeight = 1;

    private void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y < threshold) {
            // Note, I keep the x and z position the same, as it sounds like that's what you were looking for. Change as needed
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, resetHeight, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

If putting the behavior on the player prefab itself isn't acceptable for some reason, here is a modified version of your code snippet that might solve the issue:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ResetPlayerPosition : NetworkManager {

    public float threshold = -2f;

    // On button click, it checks the players position and resets the position if values are true
    public void ResetPosition () {
        var Players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

        foreach(GameObject Player in Players) {
            // Reset player position if the players Y axis is less than -2
            if (Player.transform.position.y < threshold) {
                Debug.Log("player position has been reset");
                Player.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Player position Y is currently at: " + Player.transform.position.y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll note that instead of retrieving one game object with the player tag, we retrieve all of them, and perform the evaluation against all of them with the foreach loop. This should yield more consistent behavior.

Beyond this, I would look into using a [NetworkTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkTransform.html), which will help keep the positions of players synced across the network for all movements; an essential tool for almost all networked games.

Comment: Strangely enough, your first suggestion which is simular to mine works when you convert it to and Update() instead of OnClick. It appears that the OnClick has a negative effect when trying to reset the players position in an online match.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! Putting it in Update means that every frame it will check. It also means it's run on host and client, whereas OnClick will only happen on the machine that had the click event and not get sent across the network (unless you add code to do so).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a MonoBehaviour Script and attach it to the player objects?
By this you already have the right Player GameObject and you don't have to find the GameObject with the Tag.

Comment: Well, i tried that. Since there's no player on the scene before someone host a server, i attached the script to the Player prefab, meaning, on connecting to game, the player gets a player object assigned automaticly thanks to the Network Manager script. The objects that gets created have the same name Player(Clone)

Comment: @Christian If you attach the script to the player Gameobject you already have access to the gameobject and transform variables. You don't have to use GameObject.FindWithTag("Player")

Comment: Its not wokring.

[See this image](https://imgur.com/P7FSvZp).

If i do as you said, it keeps saying that the objects position is 1.1 but its not. you can clearly see up in the right top corner that it's way less then that.

The script is attached to the prefab which is used for the Network Manager to create a clone object of that prefab. I guess, since its an online game, it's just not reacting to this way of doing it, i mean, i understand what you're saying, it also makes good sense, but since it isn't working, im assuming i have to get some sort of ID of the object to specify it ?

Comment: Ohh and btw, im using the OnClick on the button Reset Player, to call the function ResetPosition()